# MySQL Fluent Api set characterset,collation and default value

Tags: mysql, ef-fluent-api

The libraries I use.
MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 - 6.9.10.0
EntityFramework - 6.0.0.0

How do I set the characterset, collation, and default value properties of my fields in the MySQL database with the Fluent API?
I have not seen such a feature in the methods of Fluent API.

Comment: You would do that in the API, that will be in the database itself. Read this chapter: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html

Comment: You know me wrong. I know that, but I want to do it in Visual Studio as Code First

Comment: Sorry, my previous sentence was missing a word (important one). What I mean is: you can **NOT** do that through code (using your api). You need to do it in the database, when you create the database and the tables you then set the collation of it.

Comment: Thank you. But I think this is a problem. There is no point in the Code First method.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-charset.html      I found such a result, but using MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions; section is not working on the project.
So I can not access the methods